# Adding HREF links to text mentioning URLs (using preg_replace)

Tags: php, preg-replace

I can see this question has been asked many times before, but I just can't get my particular implementation to work, so wondered if someone can enlighten me of the error of my ways?!

I have a Twitter feed onto my site and (using PHP) want to replace any URLs mentioned in Tweets with the relevant HTML anchor and HREF.

An example Tweet could be ...

```
No BlackBerry 10 smartphones till Q4 2012: A bad day for BlackBerry fans today after it was revealed that due to... http://t.co/lNEdUUef
```

I am using the following preg_replace in attempt to alter this ...

`$tweet2 = preg_replace('#http://\S+#i', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $tweet);`

Unfortunately this isn't making a blind bit of difference and the text is left unchanged.

Can someone spot what I've done wrong and advise accordingly?

Comment: this should help http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php#example-4296

Comment: @DorinDuminica ereg is deprecated, you shouldn't use it. Using preg is the correct way to do this

Comment: Please, no signatures in questions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$tweet2 = preg_replace( '#(http:\/\/[^ ]+)#i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $tweet );
```

It should work as expected

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
$tweet2 = preg_replace('#http://(\S+)#i', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $tweet);
```